# MacBook Pro (Mid 2012) trackpad delay / failing

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) and some days ago I realize that the trackpad mechanical click sometimes not click. I mean, the trackpad is pressed but the click not work on the first time, and I need to press for the second time works fine.

When this happen, if I to click slowly works too. This may be a hardware issue? I'm asking that because the tap click works everytime.

Comment: First suspect would be the battery is swelling - check the status with [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) - though it can't test for swelling specifically, it can tell you if it's getting tired.

Comment: According [coconutbattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) everything looks fine with the battery. I already open my macbook and don't think that the battery is swelling... The click "issue" doesn't happen every time. For me could be a software issue...

Answer (score 1):

This could also be a setting in Trackpad settings within System Preferences. Look for 'Trackpad' in System Preferences (second row of icons, fifth from left). There is a checkbox for 'Silent Clicking'. Check to see if that has been checked on by accident.

Comment: Silent click would affect clicks all the time, not sometimes as the OP stated

Comment: My MacBook doesn't have the "Silent Clicking" option on trackpad settings.

Comment: Then I would +1 the first suggestion of battery-swell, depending on heat off the motherboard (possibly determined by what apps are running that are taxing it).

Comment: It's also possible that the trackpad click connection is failing mechanically. I had a similar failure on a mid-2010 MBP; on that machine, however, the click connection failed to release, and acted as though I continued to press on the trackpad. With ifixit's help, I replaced the trackpad.